# calculate X from his derivate

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

let $x'=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ -\omega^{2} & 0\end{array}\right) x$

How can i show that X can be written as $x=\left(\begin{array}{cos}\cos \omega t \\ -\omega \sin \omega t\end{array}\right) R$

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could edit your post to address the following. Where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

$x'=R\left(\begin{array}{c}-\omega \sin \omega t \\ -\omega^2 \cos \omega t\end{array}\right) $

Simply verify that indeed
$$x'=R\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -\omega^2 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\cos{\omega t} \\ -\omega \sin{\omega t}\end{pmatrix}$$